# how i can see angular form fields in server nodejs response?

Tags: angularjs, node.js

I am new to angular js. Here i have tried to post angular form using node server.

```
Here is my code 
in register.js
    $scope.sendForm = function() {
        alert("form is good");

              $scope.fileds= $scope.data;

                var posting = $http({
                    method: 'POST',
                    /*posting to /post */
                    url: '/post',
                    data: $scope.data,

                    processData: false
                })
                posting.success(function (response) {
                    /*executed when server responds back*/
                    console.log(response); 
                    $scope.response.data = response;

                });

  };
```

and in

```
app.js server side 

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
 app.use(bodyParser());
 app.post('/post', function (req, res) {
     console.log(req.body);
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
     req.body.serverMessage = "This is response from server"
     res.end(JSON.stringify(req.body));
 });
```

Am able to see response.data as This is response from server on form. 
But how i can get filed and their values posted from form which was submitted on angular form.

Can anyone tell me ?

Answer (score 0):

Use [node-inspector](https://github.com/node-inspector/node-inspector).

1. Install node-inspector with `npm install -g node-inspector`
2. Start node-inspector by running  `node-inspector` in a shell tab
3. Start your node app in debug mode using `node --debug app.js` (I'd recommend using [nodemon](https://github.com/remy/nodemon) to restart your process whenever a change is detected)
4. Point your browser to the URL provided by node-inspector

In your app, use a debugger statement to pause your code

```
 app.post('/post', function (req, res) {
   debugger;
   res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
   req.body.serverMessage = "This is response from server"
   res.end(JSON.stringify(req.body));
 });
```

Once you hit that endpoint you'll be able to inspect the request and have the javascript console available to you. If you're familiar with Chrome Dev Tools, this will look very familiar to you.